# How to solve "Qt: Could not initialize OLE (error 80070005)" issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Rotativa to generate PDF in my Application. It's working fine in my application localhost (Development). I got the "Qt: Could not initialize OLE (error 80070005)" error once, i have deployed in my server. How to solve this issue. Thanks advance

Comment: did you ever manage to solve this?

Answer (score 6):

Go to IIS > Site > Authentication, click on "ASP.NET Impersonation" and DISABLE it

Comment: This is true, if you disable impersonation in IIS the issue gets resolved. However I need to user Impersonation on my project, is there away to get this to work without disabling impersonation?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem here-

https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2782

*We started by removing all assets (css and javascript) from the document - leaving just images and the html layout. It generated correctly through IIS. We then slowly added back resources, starting with CSS. The moment we added one of our Javascript files back it threw the OLE error again. We removed that and added some simple Javascript to the document (literally var x = 1;) and it still failed.*

For some reson wkhtmltopdf cannot find js files...

so i found the solution here-

https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1634

```
I simply had to change:
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/1.4.5/numeral.min.js"></script>
to:
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/1.4.5/numeral.min.js"></script>
(added the HTTP).
```

I also switch on server from **ActionAsPdf** to  **UrlAsPdf**

And set the url to **localhost**

```
string pthx = "http://localhost/Home/exmple?num=" + numtofind;
UrlAsPdf urlss = new UrlAsPdf(pthx) {
    FileName = "REPORT.pdf",
    CustomSwitches = "--print-media-type "
};
```

I think  the wkhtmltopdf can't find host...

Hope it will help you too...

Answer (score 0):

I use impersonation in one of my projects and I was having this same error. Then I found an SO post about dynamically turning on/off impersonation. I dynamically turn on impersonation in a controller constructor (NOT in the web.config file). Then when I need to create the PDF I turn off impersonation, create my PDF, and turn on impersonation again. Here is the SO link about dynamic impersonation [Dynamic impersonation in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021414/dynamic-impersonation-in-asp-net)

Here is my Rotativa implementation. Note that I am using the UrlAsPdf approach:

```
// Turn off impersonation
Impersonation.undoImpersonation();

string pdfFilename = "your-file-name";

string custSwitch = "--disable-smart-shrinking --footer-line --footer-font-size \"8\" --page-size \"A4\" --orientation \"Portrait\"";
var rotativaOptions = new DriverOptions() { CustomSwitches = custSwitch };

var PDFresult = new UrlAsPdf("url-to-your-action_include-the-http(s)-part")
{
    RotativaOptions = rotativaOptions
};

var byteArray = PDFresult.BuildPdf(ControllerContext);

// Turn on impersonation, might need it for file uploads and retrieval
Impersonation.impersonateValidUser(impUser, impDomain, impPass);

return File(byteArray, "application/pdf", pdfFilename);
```